# What are the ways of escaping Ring of Spears?

Tags: smite

[Odin](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Odin) has an ultimate ability called "Ring of Spears". Using it calls down a ring of spears around him, trapping other gods within its vicinity and buffing Odin and his team-mates.
I believe it's normal to be able to escape Ring of Spears via maneuvers that can pass through walls such as Neith's back-flip, Combat Blink, and Hades's burrow. In particular, I'm wondering if it's normal and/or consistent to be able to walk out of Odin's Ring of Spears as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET8lqMGbUtc)?

Answer (score 4):

That video is just Zeus being lucky. When the edge of the spears conflicts with a god they kind of teleport out or in (50/50) it due to collision detection and handling

Basically the only way out of ring of spears is with leap type moves, Listing each one will make this answer too long and out of date quickly as new gods are released constantly. As you said blink also works for gods without a leap.

Comment: Update: I believe Osiris is able to escape from Odin's ult when he's phased.